# Using MvvmCross in a web project

Tags: silverlight, web, mvvmcross

Is there a way or plans to target a web UI with MvvmCross?

I have done a lot of XAML and I was looking around the source code for a Cirrious.MvvmCross.Silverlight

If not, is there any reason that this couldn't be written?
It seems like I could clone one of the other platform projects and make an SL target.
Or has anyone done anything similar for the web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Silverlight port has been already done at least once - but sadly the people who ported it didn't contribute it back to open source.

As long as you are targeting a modern version of SL which supports PCLs, then the port should be very straight-forward. Starting from winphone  or wpf should be quickest. There will, of course, be some 'mobile' plugins which won't make sense in-browser, but that's the same as is the case for wpf and .mac desktop apps.

The main reason I haven't done an SL port to daye is because no-one's really asked for it (and because if i think about Silverlight too long then MS's RT makes me feel sad)

Comment: Thanks, if I go that route I'll try to give back.  I'm just getting started with this framework now and already I'm hooked.