# MVVMCross support for asp.net programming?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, xamarin, mvvmcross

MVVMCross ironically doesn't seem to include Asp.NET as a supported platform. Would it be hard to use MVVMCross under an Asp.NET environment implementing views? Has anyone done this? What would need to be done.

The underlying exercise would be to retain as much code independence across Windows, iOS, Android, Mac and a Web interface - Ideally ASP.NET using mono on Unix.

Comment: Ironically? "Asp.NET environment implementing WPF views"... Do you mean Silverlight?

Comment: I mean ironically because MVVM which MVVMCross is based came from ASP.NET originally.

Comment: Are you sure? MVVM is just a pattern and was not based on ASP .NET? Like ASP .NET MVC is not something new, MVC as a pattern has been around a long time.

Comment: while MVVM is a pattern if you download the Microsoft PRISM stuff there is an actual implementation which I'm guessing is what most people use.

Comment: I'm not really talking abstract patterns, I'm interested in specific implementation details.

Comment: Mvvm was a term created by John Grossman at Microsoft in 2005 when he was working on desktop client apps in Longhorn/Avalon - which became Vista/Wpf - so Mvvm did not really come out of ASP.Net

Answer (score 1):

MonoCross, one of the 'inspirations' for MvvmCross, did actually support web-based views alongside server-based viewControllers.

However, in my opinion it had limited use, required too much server-side memory, placed limitations on mobile app design and really wasn't a good programming model for many webapps.

If you really wanted to support MvvmCross in a webapp then you could look at:

- where you will put the division of logic between web-browser-client and server
- how the server(s) will maintain session state
- how the HTML/Javascript clients will communicate in-page with the server
- how remote-client specific errors will be overcome

For a specific category of apps, there is perhaps some sense in doing this.

But for more general web apps, I think there are far better solutions out there - using knockout, angular, Nancy, Fubu, ASP.Net, etc

MvvmCross remains focussed on rich client apps where local in-memory state is commonly much larger than in web-apps.

Alternatively...

- at least two people have started on Silverlight MvvmCross ports (but I've not seen the output of either)

  - see [Using MvvmCross in a web project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386228/using-mvvmcross-in-a-web-project/16386386#16386386)
  - https://github.com/Larochem/Cirrious.Mvvmcross.Silverlight
- one open source dev is promising a future all-platform-including-html mvvm engine called Carnival (I've not seen this in the flesh yet but he does have it working on an internal project)